# Executar código php dentro de uma variável

Tags: php, closures

Boa noite pessoal

Há a possibilidade de rodar isso:

```
<?php

$variavel = 'foreach($v1 as $v2){echo $v2;};';

echo $variavel;

?>
```

Ou existe alguma forma rodar uma classe dentro de uma variável (uma function eu sei que tem):

```
<?php
$variavel = 'class teste(){function oi(){echo 'oi';}}';
echo $variavel->teste->oi();
?>
```

algo do tipo.

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Só uma pergunta, qual o objetivo disto?

Comment: É um template engine ou vai rodar um bloco de código armazenado?

Comment: Bom dia amigo, o objetivo disso é para o seguinte: Eu utilizo o doctrine ORM, assim, eu tenho todas as tabelas e campos do meu banco mapeadas em classes. Só que se eu quiser tive uma ideia do cliente poder adicionar mais campos na tabela. O legal, é que os campos padrões (campos escritos direto no arquivo php) não poderão ser apagados, ele poderá apenas apagar os campos (variaveis e gets e sets) que ele criou. Entendeu? Um abraço

Comment: Papa Charlie, a respeito do template engine, eu vou usar para isso também. Eu não sabia como dar o nome para a minha criação! srsrsr Não sabia que isso se chamava template engine! Mas fiquei feliz em saber que a minha ideia não existe em funcionamento ainda. Obrigado amigo. Abraço

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$clazz = "class teste(){function oi(){echo 'oi';}}"; 

eval($clazz); 

$variavel = new teste; 

echo $variavel->show();

$variavel->show(); 
?>
```

Tenta isso.

Comment: Legal brother!! Muito obrigado!!

Mais uma dúvida, pq eu não consigo criar uma variável dentro:
`$clazz = "class teste(){` **public $oi;** `function oi(){echo 'oi';}}";`

Comment: Achei aqui, obrigado:
`<?php 
$clazz = "class SomeClass { var \$value = 'somevalue'; function show() { echo get_class(\$this);}}"; 

eval($clazz); 

$instance = new SomeClass; 

// Here output 'somevalue'; 
echo $instance->value; 

echo "<br>"; 

//Here output 'someclass' 
$instance->show(); 
?>`
Fonte: [http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php#46382]

Comment: lembre-se que "o eval é a raiz de todo mal"

Comment: To ligado, andei lendo sobre ele já! Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Use a função **eval()**. Acabei de ver essa possibilidade também com essa função. Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro caso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
$funcao = function($variaveis) {
    foreach ($vriaveis as $variavel) {
        echo $variavel . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$valores = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
$funcao($valores);
```

Já o segundo caso é possível fazer com PHP 7 usando classes anônimas:

```
$classe = new class {
    public function oi() {
        echo 'oi' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$classe->oi();
```